# Rails 3 - Nested Resources Generating in-valid URL via form_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following form_for tag, the profile is with the URL that it is generating, it is not valid i.e here is the tag:

```
<%= form_for([current_user,@profile], :html =>{:class => "contact_form",:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
```

which is predicting this "action="/users/1/profile.1" which should be action="/users/1/profile/1"

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Below are some snapshots from the relevant rails files.

routes.rb

```
devise_for :users
resources :users, :only => [:delete] do
  resource :profile
end
```

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, :inverse_of => :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
```

Profile Model

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :user
```

rake routes output:

```
new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)              devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)          devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)         devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                       devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)               devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                  devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                       devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                       devise/registrations#destroy
            user_profile POST   /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#create
        new_user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/profile/new(.:format)  profiles#new
       edit_user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/profile/edit(.:format) profiles#edit
                         GET    /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#show
                         PUT    /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#update
                         DELETE /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#destroy
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem. my solution was, that you have to declare the url directly like this:

```
<%= form_for([current_user,@profile], :url => user_profile_path, :html =>{:class => "contact_form",:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
```

although i don't really know why this thing occurs - perhaps anyone could explain...